# How do you initialize an ActiveModel::Serializer class with an ActiveRecord::Relation array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I have a serializer

```
class FundingSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, 

  has_one :user
  has_one :tournament
  embed :ids, include: true
end
```

That initializes with the proper associations

```
FundingSerializer.new(Funding.first).to_json
```

yields

```
"{\"users\":[{\"id\":2,\"first_name\":\"Nick\"}],\"tournaments\":[{\"id\":1,\"end_date\":\"2013-07-21T23:18:54.981Z\",\"start_date\":\"2013-07-14T23:18:54.980Z\"}],\"funding\":{\"id\":1}}"
```

but,

```
FundingSerializer.new(Funding.all).to_json
```

gets this error.

```
undefined method `read_attribute_for_serialization' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Funding:0x007f998910a250>
    from /Users/nicholasshook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@pokerfund/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:121:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/nicholasshook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@pokerfund/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:68:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/nicholasshook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@pokerfund/gems/active_model_serializers-0.8.1/lib/active_model/serializer.rb:99:in `block in attribute'
    from (eval):3:in `_fast_attributes'
    from /Users/nicholasshook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@pokerfund/gems/active_model_serializers-0.8.1/lib/active_model/serializer.rb:466:in `rescue in attributes'
    from /Users/nicholasshook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@pokerfund/gems/active_model_serializers-0.8.1/lib/active_model/serializer.rb:454:in `attributes'
    from /Users/nicholasshook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@pokerfund/gems/active_model_serializers-0.8.1/lib/active_model/serializer.rb:478:in `_serializable_hash'
    from /Users/nicholasshook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@pokerfund/gems/active_model_serializers-0.8.1/lib/active_model/serializer.rb:360:in `serializable_hash'
    from /Users/nicholasshook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@pokerfund/gems/active_model_serializers-0.8.1/lib/active_model/serializer.rb:344:in `as_json'
    from /Users/nicholasshook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@pokerfund/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:50:in `block in encode'
    from /Users/nicholasshook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@pokerfund/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:81:in `check_for_circular_references'
    from /Users/nicholasshook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@pokerfund/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:49:in `encode'
    from /Users/nicholasshook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@pokerfund/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:34:in `encode'
    from /Users/nicholasshook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@pokerfund/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/to_json.rb:16:in `to_json'
    from /Users/nicholasshook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@pokerfund/gems/active_model_serializers-0.8.1/lib/active_model/serializer.rb:333:in `to_json'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/nicholasshook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@pokerfund/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/nicholasshook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@pokerfund/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/nicholasshook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@pokerfund/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
```

I do not want to simply render json: Funding.all because I would like to pass this json around to other objects in my rails application and with an angularjs app. Thanks,

Comment: Although, [SandOnTeeth's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39318636/1836143) might work, this is not the official API. Please, refer to the [the documentation](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/howto/outside_controller_use.md#using-activemodelserializers-outside-of-a-controller).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Now you can do that in this way (using AMS v0.10.2):

```
ActiveModel::Serializer.serializer_for(Funding.all).to_json
```

EDIT (03.03.2017)
This method is not working anymore. Use [aNoble's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39606516/6793532) answer:

```
ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(Funding.all).to_json
```

Comment: As of version `0.10.2` [aNoble](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39606516/1836143) provides the correct answer. Also, check out [the documentation](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/howto/outside_controller_use.md#using-activemodelserializers-outside-of-a-controller) on the topic.

Comment: I 'm using AMS 0.10.2, ActiveModel::Serializer.serializer_for(Leaderboard.all).to_json,  always returuns "{ }" if even there are dozens of Leaderboard records

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalIqbal please, check my updated answer

Answer (score 177):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(Funding.all, each_serializer: FundingSerializer).to_json
```

See this [Thoughtbot blog post](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/50091183897/fast-json-apis-in-rails-with-key-based-caches-and) for an example.

Comment: Awesome, just what I needed. This should be on the AMS wiki on github.

Comment: This gives me `uninitialized constant ActiveModel::ArraySerializer`

Comment: I completely agree with you @MatjazMuhic.

Comment: @MirkoAkov it is now for a while. Added by me. :)

Comment: I am getting a `Load Error` as I am calling it from `lib/modules`. What should be the `require ` file syntax for it?

Comment: did you add `gem "active_model_serializers"` to your gemfile?

Comment: This does not work for "active_model_serializers" gem >= 0.10.0. ::ActiveModel::ArraySerializer was moved to ::ActiveModel::Serializer::ArraySerializer and structure of classes has been significantly changed.

Comment: @DanFairaizl Looks like your wish might come true soon.

Comment: @ZekeFast for anyone googling their way over here treading the waters of the latest AMS master (as of April 2016) and found themselves dealing with this problem, please keep in mind that you need to use

ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer

instead since apparently the AMS team will be deprecating the other class soon.


ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer.new(object.myrelation, each_serializer: MySerializer)

Comment: `ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer.new(object.myrelation, serializer: MySerializer)` worked for me (`each_serializer` option was ignored)

Comment: The mentioned approach with `CollectionSerializer` works only, if you want to use the `attributes` adapter. What's more, even if that works, this API is not public and should not be used. The official API for this is via `ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource`. For more info, see [the documentation](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/howto/outside_controller_use.md#using-activemodelserializers-outside-of-a-controller).

Answer (score 28):

I'm not sure if this is an idiomatic solution, but it should work:

```
Funding.all.map{|f| FundingSerializer.new(f)}.to_json
```

Comment: that did work, I just thought that there would be a solution along the lines of ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new …

Comment: Under the hood of [ActiveModel::ArraySerializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/lib/active_model/serializer/array_serializer.rb) is basically this exact implementation. map over the collection and return a a serialized instance.

Comment: Does not work properly on "active_model_serializers" >= 0.10.0.

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me in version `0.10.2`:

`ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(Funding.all, each_serializer: FundingSerializer).to_json`

Comment: `ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource` is the current official API and this answer is the correct one, as of version `0.10.2`.

Comment: Confirming this is the only current correct answer here.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like they are adjusting this again in the newest ActiveModel::Serializers gem version. You no longer can call to_json on the ArraySerializer (which is not ActiveModel::Serializer::ArraySerializer).

Here's what I did to get around it.

```
let(:resource)        { Funding.all }
let(:serializer)      { ActiveModel::Serializer::ArraySerializer.new(resource, each_serializer: FundingSerializer)
let(:serialization)   { ActiveModel::Serializer::Adapter.create(serializer) }
subject               { JSON.parse(serialization.to_json) }
```

Calling subject will get you the json you are after.

Here are a couple of more resources which dive into testing setup for further reading: 
http://eclips3.net/2015/01/24/testing-active-model-serializer-with-rspec/
https://robots.thoughtbot.com/validating-json-schemas-with-an-rspec-matcher

Answer (score 6):

You can explicitly provide the collection serializer as well.

```
render json: Funding.all, serializer: ActiveModel::ArraySerializer, each_serializer: FundingSerializer
```

Comment: This is the right answer, at least for versions < 0.10. You can just pass in each_serializer as an option.

Comment: It works for me when I remove serializer: ActiveModel::ArraySerializer

Answer (score 3):

Testing the response for `active_model_serializers` with version `>= 0.10.0` I've done this simple helper for RSpec:

```
module AMSHelper
  def ams_array_serializer(collection, options: {}, adapter: :json)
    serializer = ActiveModel::Serializer::ArraySerializer.new(collection)
    adapter_class = ActiveModel::Serializer::Adapter.adapter_class(adapter)
    adapter_class.new(serializer, options)
  end

  def ams_serializer(object, options: {}, adapter: :json)
    serializer = ActiveModel::Serializer.serializer_for(object).new(object)
    adapter_class = ActiveModel::Serializer::Adapter.adapter_class(adapter)

    adapter_class.new(serializer, options)
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include AMSHelper, type: :request
end
```

So you can simply test with:

```
RSpec.describe "Posts", type: :request do
  describe "GET /" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get posts_path
      expect(response_body).to eq(ams_array_serializer(Post.all).to_json)
    end
  end
end
```

I hope this could be useful for someone.

Comment: `ams_serializer` is working but  `ams_array_serializer` is not working. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36278413/serialize-an-array-of-models-using-active-model-serializers

Answer (score 1):

assume you have a serializer class(Foo) not match your resources name(Bar), I use following approach to easily serialize objects:

```
class BaseSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  def self.collection_serialize(resources)
    ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(resources, each_serializer: self)
  end
end
```

let Foo serializer inherit BaseSerializer:

```
class FooSerializer < BaseSerializer
  ...
end
```

use FooSerializer in controller or outside:

```
bar = Bar.all
FooSerializer.collection_serialize(bar).to_json
```