# How to serialize hash values with active-model-serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers

I have a serializer `FooSerializer` serializing my model `Foo`. The serializer works. But in one of my controller I do a `render json: { key: [foo_1, foo_2] }` and the instances `foo_1` and `foo_2` are not serialized with `FooSerializer` (only a `to_json` is called I guess).

How to do it with a cleaner way than calling `FooSerializer` specifically on each item of the array ?

Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/17914893/1807403