# Serialize an array of models using active_model_serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers, json-api

I am trying to send the serialized version of a model to a view as a param, using the gem [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers)

```
#app/serializers/admin_serializer.rb
class AdminSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :email, :access_locked?
end


#app/controllers/dashboard/admins_controller.rb
  def index
    @search = Admin.search(params[:q])
    @admins = @search.result(:distinct => true).page(params[:page]).per(10)

    @page_entries_info = view_context.page_entries_info @admins
    # render json: @admins
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
      format.json {render json: @admins}
    end
  end



#app/views/dashboard/admins/index.html.erb
  <%= debug (ActiveModel::Serializer::Adapter.adapter_class(:json_api).new(ActiveModel::Serializer.serializer_for(@admins.first).new(@admins.first),{}).to_json) %>
  <%= debug (@admins.all.map{|admin| AdminSerializer.new(admin).to_json}) %>
```

Above debugs are yielding the below response:

```
--- '{"data":{"id":"1","type":"admins","attributes":{"email":"tech@bluesapling.com","access_locked?":false}}}' //returned by the first debug


---
- '{"object":{"id":36,"email":"aubrey_schmitt@feeneykoch.io","created_at":"2016-03-28T05:15:17.546Z","updated_at":"2016-03-28T05:15:17.546Z"},"instance_options":{},"root":null,"scope":null}'
- '{"object":{"id":20,"email":"alysa_johnston@thompson.io","created_at":"2016-03-28T05:15:16.304Z","updated_at":"2016-03-28T05:15:16.304Z"},"instance_options":{},"root":null,"scope":null}'
- '{"object":{"id":22,"email":"kristofer.langosh@kunzeluettgen.com","created_at":"2016-03-28T05:15:16.459Z","updated_at":"2016-03-28T05:15:16.459Z"},"instance_options":{},"root":null,"scope":null}'
- '{"object":{"id":37,"email":"beryl_keler@wiza.biz","created_at":"2016-03-28T05:15:17.624Z","updated_at":"2016-03-28T05:15:17.624Z"},"instance_options":{},"root":null,"scope":null}'
- '{"object":{"id":5,"email":"wilhelmine_buckridge@crona.io","created_at":"2016-03-28T05:15:15.139Z","updated_at":"2016-03-28T05:15:15.139Z"},"instance_options":{},"root":null,"scope":null}'
- '{"object":{"id":14,"email":"edward_wisoky@corkery.net","created_at":"2016-03-28T05:15:15.838Z","updated_at":"2016-03-28T05:15:15.838Z"},"instance_options":{},"root":null,"scope":null}'
- '{"object":{"id":27,"email":"leonor@jerde.biz","created_at":"2016-03-28T05:15:16.848Z","updated_at":"2016-03-28T05:15:16.848Z"},"instance_options":{},"root":null,"scope":null}'
- '{"object":{"id":2,"email":"carley@wyman.net","created_at":"2016-03-28T05:15:14.873Z","updated_at":"2016-03-28T05:15:14.873Z"},"instance_options":{},"root":null,"scope":null}'
- '{"object":{"id":10,"email":"ervin.gleichner@cremin.org","created_at":"2016-03-28T05:15:15.527Z","updated_at":"2016-03-28T05:15:15.527Z"},"instance_options":{},"root":null,"scope":null}'
- '{"object":{"id":15,"email":"lonzo.dickens@johnscole.name","created_at":"2016-03-28T05:15:15.916Z","updated_at":"2016-03-28T05:15:15.916Z"},"instance_options":{},"root":null,"scope":null}'
```

In the first debug I am serializing only one object, while in the second one I am trying to do it for an array of objects.
The first debug is correctly returning the serialized version of the object(in json_api format) while second debug is not.
Tried ArraySerializer as well, with no success: `ActiveModel::Serializer::ArraySerializer.new(@admins, each_serializer: AdminSerializer).as_json`
how do I achieve the desired serialization. Moreover, if achieved, can I used some other simplified version of this? As this debug statement is way too verbose.

Tried all the solutions mentioned here - [How do you initialize an ActiveModel::Serializer class with an ActiveRecord::Relation array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17542793/how-do-you-initialize-an-activemodelserializer-class-with-an-activerecordrel/17572992#17572992)

**The basic problem which I am trying to solve is, in the index method of the Admin controller, the Admin object is passed as a PORO to the index.html file. But I want the serialized json version of this object so that I can pass it to my react components as a prop**

index method is rendering proper json on firing http://dashboard.localhost.com:3000/admins.json 
[image]

**UPDATE#1** for the index method

```
def index
    @search = Admin.search(params[:q])
    @admins_array = @search.result(:distinct => true).to_a
    if params[:page]
      @admins = @search.result(:distinct => true).page(params[:page][:number]).per(10)
      @admins_json_array = Kaminari.paginate_array(@admins_array).page(params[:page][:number]).per(10)
    else
      @admins = @search.result(:distinct => true).page(1).per(10)
      @admins_json_array = Kaminari.paginate_array(@admins_array).page(1).per(10)
    end
    @admins_json = ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(@admins_json_array.to_a)
    ...
    ...
    ...
end
```

Comment: Do you have a repo I could clone and try this out in?

Comment: No, I can't do that. Not privileged enough

Comment: Can you make a small repository with just enough code to replicate the problem?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I have a controller that I need to specify the serializer in, due to wanting different attributes from the default serializer.

In Controller:

```
  def index
    search = User.ransack(search_params)
    render json: search.result, each_serializer: MembershipRenewalSerializer::MemberSerializer
  end
```

So, just to get things working, what happens if you specify the `each_serializer` option?

### Edits:

Outside Controller:

```
ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(
  User.first(2), 
  each_serializer: MembershipRenewalSerializer::MemberSerializer
).to_json
```

Note, that without specifying `each_serializer`, `SerializableResource` would use the `UserSerializer`.

### Edit #2,

It looks like there is something weird happening with the @admins data.

Try converting to an array:

```
ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(@admins.to_a).to_json
```

### Edit #3

To paginate your array, try the following:

```
@search = Admin.search(params[:q])
@results = @search.result(:distinct => true).to_a
@admins = Kaminari.paginate_array(@results).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

Comment: index render json is working as expected and rendering the json in the correct format as specified by the json_api. updated my question, to reflect this state

Comment: this worked for me in my rails console: `ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(User.first(2)).to_json`

Comment: `<%= debug(ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(@admins.first(2)).to_json) %>` works for me too.. but sadly `<%= debug(ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(@admins).to_json) %>` doesn't. leads to `undefined method `query_parameters' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: I wonder if `@admins` is some weird object... what happens when you tack on a `.to_a` to admins, so `@admins.to_a`. Also, could you give the output of `@admins.class.name`?

Comment: (byebug) @admins.class.name
"ActiveRecord::Relation"

Comment: well, this could be a bug then. Did `to_a` fix your problem for now?

Comment: (byebug) @admins.to_a
[#<Admin id: 36, email: "aubrey_schmitt@feeneykoch.io", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$u1E0eoEymfPs.rmUu9K....

Comment: right, but did `ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(@admins.to_a).to_json` work out?

Comment: oh yes, it worked like charm. `<%= debug(ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(@admins.to_a).to_json) %>`

Comment: What is the underlying problem? Shall I ping you on slack?

Comment: might be easier, yeah. I'm still trying to figure out how to replicate this myself on my machine.

Comment: Can you post this as an answer, so that I can accept this

Comment: Added. I also pinged you on slack in the #needhelp channel for followup

Comment: How do I add the pagination links now?

Comment: maybe on your array, call `@paginated_array = Kaminari.paginate_array(@your_array).page(3).per(1)`?

Comment: @vipin8169 I added an edit #3 to my post, with the pagination tip

Comment: updated the index method as per your suggestion, still couldn't get the pagination data

Comment: is there any way you could make a small repo replicating this? It would help out the ams team a ton :-)

Comment: posted a new sol - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36301450/get-kaminari-pagination-links-in-the-json-generated-by-the-active-model-serializ

Comment: `ActiveModel::SerializableResource` has been deprecated in favor of `ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource`

Answer (score 2):

Follow the guide: [Serializing before controller render](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/howto/outside_controller_use.md#serializing-before-controller-render)

You could use `ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(@admins, adapter: :json_api).to_json`

in `index.html.erb`

```
<%= debug (ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(@posts, adapter: :json_api).to_json) %>
```

below is the output(using posts)

```
'{"data":[{"id":"1","type":"posts","attributes":{"title":"first post","body":null}},{"id":"2","type":"posts","attributes":{"title":"second post","body":null}}],"links":{}}
```

Comment: It didn't work. still didn't get the data in the specified format

Comment: PS: I am doing this in view files.

Comment: I forgot the '.to_json'. Try it.

Comment: without to_json, atleast I am getting some data. I get the following exception as soon as I append to_json => `undefined method query_parameters for nil:NilClass`  https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/1268

Comment: As the edited answer, I'm sure it worked to `@posts` which is array of Post instances. Could you print what's in your `@admins` for further debug?

Comment: Yes, I posted the entire output here, please see the last comment - https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/1268

Comment: ActiveModel::SerializableResourcenew(model) worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I create a concern with some API helper methods and there you can check if its a collection pass find the appropiate serializer and pass it to the collection serializer.

```
def api_response(data)
  render json: wrap_answer(data)
end

def wrap_answer(data)
  if data.respond_to?(:each)
    ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer.new(data, each_serializer: ActiveModel::Serializer.serializer_for(data.first))
  else
    data
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

should have made that into string and use json.stringify to make that as a string and make your life easy

Comment: See [answer] on how to post a complete answer, not a suggestion