# Get kaminari pagination links in the JSON generated by the active model serializer

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4, kaminari, active-model-serializers, json-api

I am trying to convert @admins to JSON using the AdminSerializer

```
#app/serializers/admin_serializer.rb
class AdminSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :email, :access_locked?
end
```

where Admins is>> `@admins = @search.result(:distinct => true).page(params[:page][:number]).per(10)` and `@search = Admin.search(params[:q])`

When I execute this command>> `ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(@admins.to_a).as_json` I do get the desired JSON, but the pagination links are missing from the JSON received, as they were lost while converting the `@admins` to array using `to_a`.
However, when I execute `render :json => @admins` , I get the complete JSON with the pagination links in it, as shown inn the screenshot below:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [latest commit](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/396395666fa18804963276666fe15111757d2c4b) available you need to use:

```
resource = ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(@admins)
resource.to_json(serialization_context: ActiveModelSerializers::SerializationContext.new(request))
```

Comment: One more doubt that I have is, `@admins_json = ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(@admins.to_a).as_json` is returning me a JSON, while the method described above gives a string, which I have to parse using `JSON.parse()` of javascript. do I have to call to_json again to convert it into a JSON?

Answer (score 2):

I used kaminari it's great pagination gem
and i cant add paginataion in json response
but i found and custom code.

```
#your controller#index
require 'pagination'
...your code
render json: Pagination.build_json(@posts, @comment_page, @comment_per)

# /lib/pagination.rb
class Pagination
  def self.build_json object, nested_page = 1, nested_per = 10
    ob_name = object.name.downcase.pluralize
    json = Hash.new
    json[ob_name] = ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(object.to_a, nested_page: nested_page, nested_per: nested_per)
    json[:pagination] = {
        current_page: object.current_page,
        next_page: object.next_page,
        prev_page: object.prev_page,
        total_pages: object.total_pages,
        total_count: object.total_count
    }
    return json
  end
end
```