# Active Model Serializer - Serialize Model with multiple key and value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

Most of the questions on SO seems to be too outdated to solve this problem.

I want to serialize a model. 
Here's what my serializer looks like -

```
class AssignmentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  belongs_to :lesson, class_name: "Lesson"
  attributes :id, :student_id, :tutor, :name, :start_date, :end_date, :description, :lesson
end
```

This works perfectly well for situations where you want to serialize a single object in this form.

```
def index
    if current_user&.student?
        @assignments = Assignment.where(student_id: current_user.id)
        @assignments_due = Assignment.find_due(current_user)
        @submitted_assignments = Assignment.find_submitted(current_user)
    elsif current_user&.tutor?
        @assignments = Assignment.where(tutor_id: current_user.id)
    end
    respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: @assignments }
    end
end
```

But doesn't work when I want to serialize multiple objects like so:

```
def index
    if current_user&.student?
        @assignments = Assignment.where(student_id: current_user.id)
        @assignments_due = Assignment.find_due(current_user)
        @submitted_assignments = Assignment.find_submitted(current_user)
    elsif current_user&.tutor?
        @assignments = Assignment.where(tutor_id: current_user.id)
    end
    respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: {
            assignments: @assignments,
            assignments_due: @assignments_due,
            submitted_assignments: @submitted_assignments
            }, each_serializer: AssignmentSerializer
        }
    end
end
```

I have tried multiple methods by following different methods I saw in this [documentation](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/general/serializers.md#read_attribute_for_serializationkey) but none seems to work.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

### Update tried as suggested in answer and comment, but this approach did not work. Tried with and without the each_serializer key

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: {
        assignments: @assignments.as_json,
        assignments_due: @assignments_due.as_json,
        submitted_assignments: @submitted_assignments.as_json
        }, each_serializer: AssignmentSerializer
    }
end
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `@assignments.as_json`?

Comment: tried as_json both with that each_serializer and without it, still did not work.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, the answer was right there all along, it was just a bit confusing. 
In the same link I shared I found the answer. [This link](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/general/serializers.md#read_attribute_for_serializationkey)

So this is how I did it, using `ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new`

```
def index
    if current_user&.student?
        @assignments = Assignment.where(student_id: current_user.id)
        @assignments_due = Assignment.find_due(current_user)
        @submitted_assignments = Assignment.find_submitted(current_user)
    elsif current_user&.tutor?
        @assignments = Assignment.where(tutor_id: current_user.id)
    end
    respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: {
            assignments: ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(@assignments),
            assignments_due: ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(@assignments_due),
            submitted_assignments: ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(@submitted_assignments)
            }
        }
    end
end
```

That gave me the exact structure that I wanted.

Comment: I was posting a solution like you just found, based on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36278413/serialize-an-array-of-models-using-active-model-serializers

Comment: @iGian thank you very much. I didn't find this link while I was searching.

Answer (score 0):

As per: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/serializers/json.rb#L89

`@assignments.as_json` should serialize your `assignments` using `AssignmentSerializer` as you want to achieve.

Comment: that didn't work. I'll update my question to show u how i used it.

Comment: I found a solution for it man, thanks for taking the time to post an answer. Check out my solution above.